# I'm trying to plot a histogram of log returns (% values) for about 240 monthly returns

Tags: rstudio

I'm trying to plot a histogram of log returns (% values) for about 240 monthly returns. Can someone help me with this? My returns are contained in a vector, but I'm unable to specify bin range, etc.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you be more specific about what trouble you've encountered?

Comment: I tried doing it in excel first but what I got was a histogram with 240 bins. How do I plot a histogram in R that would give me a smaller frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"returns" is your vector
you can change bin by altering the "breaks"

hist(returns,breaks=100)
hist(returns,breaks=200)